# Is wild camping legal in Romania?

Tags: legal, camping, romania

I'm interested in setting up a tent in a forest in Romania. Would this be legal to do as of 2016?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wild camping is not allowed in Romania, there is a law ([Legea 54/2012](http://www.legalis.ro/2012/03/29/legea-picnicului-legea-542012-amenzi-de-la-100-la-50000-de-lei/) privind desfasurarea activitatilor de picnic) which does not allow it. But... yes, it is still tolerated. A special attention at the natural reservations (The Danube Delta in particular).

An interactive map with camping sites in Romania as well as a downloadable guide can be found here: http://takethelongwayhome.eu/

Comment: Huh? I was in the Carpathian Mountains and saw large signs indicating how one should not feed the bears while camping in the wild, and a hiking book I own (translated from Romanian to German) indicates it is allowed outside nature reserves.

Answer (score 2):

I just spoke to my Romanian friend, who confirmed that this is technically legal.  Having said that, it's not the safest thing ever, as Romania is known for high crime/theft rate against campers. If you're in the wild somewhere, it may be that much more difficult to get help if needed. There's some discussion of wild camping in Romania at this thread - http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/europe/warning-free-camping-in-romania-27342

It may be safer/more advisable to stay at a camp site - there's a list of campsites in Romania here - http://www.campingo.com/romania-camping.htm

Yet, to answer your question directly, yes, it is legal to wild camp in Romania, as long as you're not doing it on somebody's private land (e.g. farm) without their express permission.

Comment: Can you also add a link to the relevant Romanian law? Or some sort of an official government website?

Comment: Your answer is just about the opposite of what I've found searching through forums and information pages. I have no legal reference either, but from the information I've found, wild camping is allegedly not allowed in Romania, but tolerated almost everywhere and commonly practiced by Romanians.  As long as you practice common sense, it is not supposed to be anymore dangerous or unsafe than wild camping anywhere else.